# How to reach 404 page through multiple htaccess rewrites

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I'm pretty novice at htaccess but I know enough to make a few simple redirects and rewrites happen. My problem is that I've never combined multiple rewrites, such as in the custom PHP/MySQL gallery system I've created, and so I'm having a few issues.

The main things I want to accomplish are to have the gallery system structured as such:
https://example.com/album
https://example.com/gallery
https://example.com/gallery/img/img-name
This is actually working successfully already, but it seems to also be catching any invalid URLs and assuming they're gallery names, so my 404 page goes completely overlooked. So for example,
https://example.com/asdf
brings up a blank gallery page when it should obviously produce the 404. Do I need to somehow have my htaccess file check my database for potential existing name conflicts? Is that possible? Or is there a simpler solution that I'm overlooking?

Here's what I have now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /album.php?a_id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /galleries.php?g_id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/img/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ img.php?g_id=$1&i_id=$2 [NC]
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Let's say the user specifies  /album only , what a_id parameter you expect to get?

Comment: The simple solution would be to use a prefix on each URL, e.g. `/album/:album`, `/gallery/:gallery`, `/gallery/img/:image`. The alternative is to attempt to match the requested album, gallery, or image, and if not found return a 404 response yourself.

Comment: @olegsv - I actually noticed that album was causing issues later last night, so I've temporarily removed it. But to answer your question, it would be an SEO-friendly name retrieved from the database - which is what the gallery pages are currently doing as well.

Comment: @fubar - Thank you! I'll look into that and see what I can do. I wasn't aware of that function in htaccess.

Comment: @MikeC to clarify, you’d be attempting to find the album, gallery or image after the request has been passed on to PHP. It is from there that you’d return a 404 response if necessary.